# Modeling a presentation with ordered slides

Tags: alloy

I’m trying to model a presentation with ordered slides, with every slide appearing in exactly one presentation.

```
sig Presentation {
    // At most #Int arrows, exactly #Slide arrows, each Int used at most once
    slides: Int one -> lone Slide
} {
    #slides > 1
}

sig Slide {} {Slide = Presentation.slides[Int]}

run {} for 5 but exactly 2 Presentation
```

I’m having trouble expressing the part about no slide being in two presentations. I’ve tried things like:

```
fact { all p1, p2: Presentation | no p1.slides[Int] & p2.slides[Int] }
fact { all slide: Slide, p1, p2: Presentation | p1 in slides.slide.Int and p2 in slides.slide.Int 
implies p1=p2 }
```

But adding those facts just causes the run command to find no instances.

I see this is very similar to the `seq` keyword described here: http://alloytools.org/quickguide/seq.html , but I haven't figured out how I would use that to specify the "exactly one presentation per slide" restriction.

What am I doing wrong? Should I move to another way of describing the ordering of slides? I’m using this way (`slides: Int-> Slide`) because I’m hoping to later implement reordering with limitations (a slide may refer to an earlier slide, and may not be moved ahead of it).

Answer (score 0):

As you sent almost the same message [on the Alloy forum](https://alloytools.discourse.group/t/modeling-a-presentation-with-ordered-slides/326), I'm copying my answer from there: technically, what you did with `slides` is encode a list of slides. I would first suggest to separate the notion of list (which could be modelled using a generic module) from that of presentation.
Now, as a matter of fact, lists already exist in the Alloy library in 3 forms, you may look at them to get inspiration or just reuse one of them. Essentially:

- `seqrel` represents a list as a relation from a set of indices to a set of elements
- `sequence` represents a list as a signature containing such a relation (thus you may manipulate lists more easily if needed)
- `sequniv` is rougly like `seqrel` except that you never open it explicitly, instead you [use the keyword `seq` to declare a list](https://alloytools.org/quickguide/seq.html) and then can use functions and predicates from `sequniv` as needed.

All these modules implement a function `elems` that will allow to retrieve the set of elements. You may use it to specify the fact that bothers you.

Comment: PS: as remarked on the Alloy forum, in at least release 6.1 (but perhaps before too), there's a typing issue with `sequence` so you ought to use `seqrel` or `sequniv` with the `seq` keyword.